# JQuery validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form which is generating while clicking on a html button .

Here is the code .

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  </head>       
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction()
  {
    alert("Hello World!");
  }
  function createDoc()
  {
    var w=window.open('','','width=400,height=300');
    w.document.open();w.document.write("<table width=350 height =200 <tr><td align=center>");
    w.document.write("<table width=300 height =200 ><tr><td>");
    w.document.write("<form class='commentform' action='hiii.php' method='GET'>");
    w.document.write("<input type='hidden' name='pcode' value='00214'>");
    w.document.write("<label>Name:</label></td><td><input type='text'id='pname' name='pname'   value=''>");
    w.document.write("</td></tr><tr><td>");
    w.document.write("<label>Email Address:</label></td><td><input type='text' name='pemail' value=''/>");
    w.document.write("</td></tr><tr><td>");
    w.document.write("<label>Mobile number:</label></td><td><input type='text' name='pnumber' value=''/>");
    w.document.write("</td></tr><tr><td align=center>");
    w.document.write("<input type='submit'  onclick='validate()' name='submit' value='Submit'/>");
    w.document.write("</form>");w.document.write("</td></tr>");
    w.document.write("</td></tr></table>");
    w.document.write("</td></tr></table>");
    w.focus();w.document.close();
  }
  function validate(){
    var pname = $('#pname').val();
    alert(pname);
  }
  </script>
  <input type="button" value="Click to Connect" onclick="createDoc()">
</html>
```

SO on clicking on Click to connect button I am getting popup which contains a form .

I am trying to apply the validation for the dynamically generated fields but instead of getting alert the form is submitted directly please tell me what might I am doing wrong here .

I want command should come to my validate function before submitting the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
w.document.write("<input type='submit'  onclick='javascript: return window.opener.validate( event, window.document );' name='submit' value='Submit'/>");

onclick='javascript: return window.opener.validate( event, window.document );'

function validate(e, w) {
    var pname = $('#pname', w).val();
    alert(pname);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Please replace above code. I think it will work.

Comment: pname is showing undefined after entering some value in input box also

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the default action. Maybe something like this. just pass the `event` to the validate method. and call `event.preventDefault()` in the validate function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    createDoc();
}


function createDoc() {
    var w=window.open('','','width=400,height=300');
    w.document.open();w.document.write("<table width=350 height =200 <tr><td align=center>");
    w.document.write("<table width=300 height =200 ><tr><td>");
    w.document.write("<form class='commentform' action='hiii.php' method='GET'>");
    w.document.write("<input type='hidden' name='pcode' value='00214'>");
    w.document.write("<label>Name:</label></td><td><input type='text'id='pname' name='pname'   value=''>");
    w.document.write("</td></tr><tr><td>");
    w.document.write("<label>Email Address:</label></td><td><input type='text' name='pemail' value=''/>");
    w.document.write("</td></tr><tr><td>");
    w.document.write("<label>Mobile number:</label></td><td><input type='text' name='pnumber' value=''/>");
    w.document.write("</td></tr><tr><td align=center>");
    w.document.write("<input type='submit'  onclick='validate(event)' name='submit' value='Submit'/>");
    w.document.write("</form>");w.document.write("</td></tr>");
    w.document.write("</td></tr></table>");
    w.document.write("</td></tr></table>");
    w.focus();w.document.close();

}

function validate(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var pname = $('#pname').val();
alert(pname);
}

</script>
```

Comment: What about `onclick='validate()'`?

Answer (score 0):

The form submit button is still being executed as it's designed to be, so you do need to stop that default behavior for your validation to run and let that function then proceed with the submission process after successful validation.

It can take experiments with form prevent methods like event.preventDefault() with jQuery but you should really utilize jQuery libraries others have developed that already comes with a function to stop form from being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the form to submit the form use

```
<input type='submit'  onclick='return false; validate();' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
```

After you validated the inputs and you want to submit the form use

```
$('.commentform').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not before you write table you include also the script because you are opening a new window, like:

```
var w=window.open('','','width=400,height=300');
w.open();
w.document.write("<head> <script type='text/javascript'>
function validate(){
var pname = $('#pname').val();
alert(pname);}
</script></head>";
w.document.write("<table width=350 height =200 <tr><td a ...more code here
```